# Changing background on mouse hover

Tags: jquery

I would like to change color of li links on mouse over at new_r_div
For that I have included  hover class at link id. On mouseouver background of element should be changed
This is my code [link](http://jsfiddle.net/xrcwrn/QQvv6) please see it

HTML

```
<div id="response"> <a href="#">Response Request</a>
    <div class="new_r_div hidden">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" id="link">Confirm</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="link">Delete</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$("#response").hover(
    function () {
        $('.new_r_div').removeClass('hidden');
    }, 
    function () {
        $('.new_r_div').addClass('hidden');
    }
);

$("#new_r_div").hover(
    function () {
        $('#link').addClass('hover');
    }, 
    function () {
        $('#link').removeClass('hover');
    }
);
```

CSS

```
.new_r_div {
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
    background:#ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: solid 2px #ccc;
    background: #99CCFF;
    z-index: 9999;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.hover {
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: new_r_div is a class and not an ID. Replace "#new_r_div" with ".new_r_div" or simply change the element. Also, IDs should be unique - here you have two elements with the ID of "link". jQuery will detect the first one and then ignore anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, you can use CSS alone for this - no jquery required:

```
.new_r_div li:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```js
$("#response").hover(
    function () {
        $('.new_r_div').removeClass('hidden');
    }, 
    function () {
        $('.new_r_div').addClass('hidden');
    }
);
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QQvv6/14/)

Answer (score 1):

# is used to select id where you need to use classSelector .Refer below code

```
$(".new_r_div").hover(function(){
    $('#link').addClass('hover');
},function(){
    $('#link').removeClass('hover');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QQvv6/9/

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a few issues with this code.  It was only working for one `a` tag since there were multiple `#link` elements.  The following code should work for both anchors.

```
$("#response").hover(function(){
    $('.new_r_div').removeClass('hidden');
},function(){
    $('.new_r_div').addClass('hidden');
});

//switched selector to only target the anchor tags
$(".new_r_div li a").hover(function(){  
    $(this).addClass('hover');  //targeting anchor tags allow us to use this
},function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/QQvv6/23/

Answer (score 0):

your  `new_r_div` is `class` and not `id` so the selector is `.`

try this

```
 $(".new_r_div").hover(function(){
 ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
jsFiddle working code: http://jsfiddle.net/joquery/QQvv6/7/

You have some errors in your code:

1. You cannot have to elements with the same id (`id="link"`)
2. `new_r_div` is not an id it's a class in your html
3. You want to hover over every listitem that is a child of `new_r_div`. So you need to write `$(".new_r_div li")` instead of `$(".new_r_div")`

I've updated you JavaScript:

```
$("#response").hover(function(){
    $('.new_r_div').removeClass('hidden');
},function(){
    $('.new_r_div').addClass('hidden');
});
$(".new_r_div li").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('hover');
},function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#new_r_div").hover(...)
```

`new_r_div` is class, not `id`

```
<li><a href="#" id="link">Confirm</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="link">Delete</a></li>
```

`id` must be unique

And your example can be written without jquery:

```
.new_r_div:hover{
    background:red;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QQvv6/19/

**Added:**
OR  http://jsfiddle.net/QQvv6/27/ (hover menu item)

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="response">
                <a href="#">Response Request</a>

<div class="new_r_div hidden">
    <ul>
        <li class="menuItem"><a href="#"  >Confirm</a></li>
        <li class="menuItem"><a href="#"  >Delete</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$("#response").hover(function(){
    $('.new_r_div').removeClass('hidden');
},function(){
    $('.new_r_div').addClass('hidden');
});

$(".menuItem").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('hover');
},function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/QQvv6/26/)

Answer (score 0):

First: You used two times the same id "link". An id can be used only ONE time in a document, an id has to be unique.
Second: The property for the background-color is "background-color" , not "background" :)
Third: You cot confused: The list container has a class, but you tried to select by id.

I guess this is what you wanted:

```
    $("#response").hover(function(){
    $('.new_r_div').removeClass('hidden');
},function(){
    $('.new_r_div').addClass('hidden');
});
$(".new_r_div").find(".link").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('hover');
},function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```